# Streaming sockets from ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, tornado, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to create a Python application in which one process (process 'A') receives a request and puts it into a ProcessPool (from concurrent.futures). In handling this request, a message may need to passed to a second process (process 'B'). I'm using tornado's iostream module to help wrap the connections and get responses.

Process A is failing to successfully connect to process B from within the ProcessPool execution. Where am I going wrong?

The client, which makes the initial request to process A:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import tornado.iostream
import tornado.ioloop

def print_message ( data ):
    print 'client received', data

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(s)
stream.connect(('localhost',2001))
stream.read_until('\0',print_message)
stream.write('test message\0')
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop().instance().start()
```

Process A, that received the initial request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.tcpserver
import tornado.iostream
import socket
import concurrent.futures
import functools

def handle_request ( data ):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
    out_stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(s)
    out_stream.connect(('localhost',2002))
    future = out_stream.read_until('\0')
    out_stream.write(data+'\0')
    return future.result()

class server_a (tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer):

   def return_response ( self, in_stream, future ):
       in_stream.write(future.result()+'\0')

   def handle_read ( self, in_stream, data ):
       future = self.executor.submit(handle_request,data)
       future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(self.return_response,in_stream))

   def handle_stream ( self, in_stream, address ):
       in_stream.read_until('\0',functools.partial(self.handle_read,in_stream))

   def __init__ ( self ):
       self.executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
       tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer.__init__(self)

server = server_a()
server.bind(2001)
server.start(0)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop().instance().start()
```

Process B, that should receive the relayed request from Process A:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.tcpserver
import functools

class server_b (tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer):

    def handle_read ( self, in_stream, data ):
        in_stream.write('server B read'+data+'\0')

    def handle_stream ( self, in_stream, address ):
       in_stream.read_until('\0',functools.partial(self.handle_read,in_stream))

server = server_b()
server.bind(2002)
server.start(0)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop().instance().start()
```

And finally, the error returned by Process A, which is raised during the 'read_until' method:

```
ERROR:concurrent.futures:exception calling callback for <Future at 0x10654b890 state=finished raised OSError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 299, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "./a.py", line 26, in return_response
    in_stream.write(future.result()+'\0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 397, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why you're getting this "Bad file descriptor" error (concurrent.futures unfortunately lost backtrace information when it was backported to 2.7), but there is no IOLoop running in the ProcessPoolExecutor's worker processes, so you won't be able to use Tornado constructs like IOStream in this context (unless you spin up a new IOLoop for each task, but that may not make much sense unless you need compatibility with other asynchronous libraries).

I'm also not sure if it works to mix tornado's multi-process mode and ProcessPoolExecutor in this way.  I think you may need to move the initialization of the ProcessPoolExecutor until after the start(0) call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have resolved the issue, by updating process A to have:

```
def stop_loop ( future ):
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().stop()

def handle_request ( data ):
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.clear_current()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.clear_instance()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
    out_stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(s)
    out_stream.connect(('localhost',2002))
    future = out_stream.read_until('\0')
    future.add_done_callback(stop_loop)
    out_stream.write(data+'\0')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    return future.result()
```

Even though the IOLoop hadn't previously been started in the spawned process, it was returning its parent loop when calling for the current instance. Clearing out those references has allowed a new loop for the process to be started. I don't know formally what is happening here though.